# Ajax 500 (Internal Server Error) Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have some problems with my AJAX code. My task is to create some dependent dropdown select box with codeigniter, so I use AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#ruangan, #ruangan_label').hide();
    $('#unit').change(function() {
        var unit_id = $('#unit').val();
        if (unit_id != "") {
            var post_url = "getruangan" + unit_id;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: post_url,
                success: function(ruangan) {
                    $('#ruangan').append(ruangan);
                }
            });
            /* $('#ruangan, #ruangan_label').show(); */
        } else {
            $('#ruangan').empty();
            $('#ruangan, #ruangan_label').hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here is my controller:

```
function getruangan($units)
{
    $unit = explode('|', $units);
    $unitkerja = $unit[0];
    $this->load->model('admin/laporanmodel', '', TRUE);
    echo (json_encode($this->laporanmodel->get_ruangan($unitkerja)));
}
```

This is my eror from console :

```
POST http://localhost:8080/simas/admin/laporan/getruangan023040500414964002KD%7CBPSPP 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.min.js:6
x.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:6
(anonymous function) @ repdbr:250
x.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:5
v.handle @ jquery.min.js:5
ListPicker._handleMouseUp @ about:blank:810

I have no problems with the connection between controller and model. Can you help me?
```

Comment: Your title suggests a 500 apache error which is not very specific. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: turn your error reporting on and see what is the real problem. change your environment to development `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');`

Comment: why are you pasing `unit_id` directly in your url when you can pass it as get/post data?

Comment: @TintuCRaju There's no error

Comment: @madalinivascu cause `unit_id` is my parameter to get from my model

Comment: there must be an error in your php page.  are you sure your error reporting is on. if it produce a `500` error then there must be a reason behind that in order to find it you need to debug your php code. Once again make sure that your error reporting is on. If it is ok then you have to put `die()` to make sure that upto that line the code is error free.

Answer (score 1):

Your function needs a parameter, however you're not sending it properly unless your variable `unit_id` contains a slash `/`.

```
var post_url = "getruangan" + unit_id;
// Output: getruangan55
```

Since you are using `POST` there is no need to send it as url parameter.

```
if(unit_id == '')
{
   $('#ruangan').empty();
   $('#ruangan, #ruangan_label').hide();

   return;
}

$.ajax(
{
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'getruangan',
   data: {'unit_id': unit_id, 'otherParam': otherValue},
   success: function(response)
   {
      $('#ruangan').append(response);
   }
});
```

From the PHP side, you can access the content through `$_POST`.

```
print_r($_POST); // To check the values passed
print_r($this->input->post('unit_id')); // To access a value
```